# pyspark: how to convert dataframes with a time column to a spark streaming object?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

Let's say you have a Spark dataframe `df` with a column `timestamp` representing time, let's say in unix-time format (seconds since 1970). How do I make Spark.Streaming treat this as an input so that I can do sliding window on the data?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, or at least not in a meaningful way. While it is possible to use `queueStream` to create stream from RDD like this:

```
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)
df = sc.parallelize([(i, ) for i in range(10000)]).toDF(["ts"])
stream = ssc.queueStream([df.rdd])
stream.count().pprint()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

where the correspondence between batch and object in queue is 1:1. Unfortunately `queueStream` is, unlike its Scala counterpart, a static stream. It is not possible to enqueue new data after it has been created. It means you have split `DataFrame` manually into multiple RDD.

Comment: Thanks @Zero323. When you call it XY I guess you mean there is another way to do what I want.  Yet, this is explicitly what I want to do. I want to be able to "playback" old data to a streaming job for testing and development before I have the real streaming input and for recooking (processing old accumulated data in a different way).

Comment: OK, removed the comment :) Personally I would rather consider creating a simple script which will push data into a stream though.

Comment: Thanks @zero323. Can you please guide how such a simple script would look like?